# Capure communications strings

Tags: string, networking, sniffing

I'm working on a software written by a developer that didn't leave any documentation for the company and I've to understand how a server communicate with a device.
I think it sends it some strings over a socket (to log-in in the device and check some parameters), I've the public IP address of the server and the public IP address of the device. 
I'd like to know if there is a way to see what the server 'tells' to this device and vice-versa, I gave a quick look to Wireshark but I can't understand how to use it correctly.

Comment: Can you tell us what OS your server and client are running?

Comment: The server is running Windows server 2008, the 'client' is a CCTV DVR with a Linux-based OS

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure exactly how it would work in a UNIX enviroment, but I use sudo tcpdump host {server IP address} via a Mac terminal and I get a live feed of any connections in or out from that IP address. Maybe some Linux guys can advise on that.